# socket reads and partial data -- sanity check needed

Tags: objective-c, sockets, tcp

Okay so, this is a general question about reads from a socket.

I'm looking at an Objective C app that someone built which uses a TCP socket library and sets up a handler for "didReadData" which takes the data and sends it to a JSON parser.

Now... am I right when I say this is basically totally wrong?  Isn't it the case that socket reads could return some, all, or none of the data, depending on lots of factors like network latency?  So isn't it the case that you have to keep reading from the socket until you get to the end of the data -- however that is delimited -- and then parse it?  So, for JSON for example, if you were sending it over HTTP you'd send a content-length header which would tell the server (or client) when it can stop reading from the socket?  So -- if you're not using http and using a raw socket, you'd have to have some other delimiter or mechanism of determining where the end of the message is.

I am wondering if this particular app has only been tested in situations where client and server are on the same host -- so I'm wondering if the programmer thinks that it works because, just coincidentally, the first read has always up until now returned all the data.

Comment: The only possibility that could work is for the server to close the connection after sending all the data.  It's a poor design, but has been used in non-critical systems where bad latency is acceptable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right.

The stream is endless and a message has to be marked as such by a delimiter. If the app you are testing relies on the stream object to identify messages without a delimiter this will be the problem.

The question is if this functionality is somehow integrated in the socket library. What library are you using?

Comment: I am not sure -- I'm not an Objective C person so I'm guessing from looking at the includes --  GCDAsyncSocket maybe?

Comment: ah ok I've used it before. It is very good but does not do any kind of data interpretation. I think you have found the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to implement a streaming parser.  I don't know if the parser in use in the code in question is such, but it's not impossible.

For example, Apple's `NSXMLParser` allows for streaming parsing.

(Edited to remove mention of `NSJSONSerialization` because, although it can read from a stream, it does so synchronously.)

Comment: I don't think it's a streaming parser because the call to the parser works like this: it passes the data and gets a dictionary object, then passes the dictionary downstream.  If I'm understanding this correctly, if it was streaming, it would have to continue to append to the existing dictionary until there were no more elements -- or something like that.